# Mysql сравнивает числа как строку

Tags: mysql

Делаю запрос например такой:

```
SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY price DESC
```

Но сравнивает только первую цифру, и поэтому 190000 считается меньше чем 200. 
Как сделать, чтобы сортировал как по числовому полю а не как по строковому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какой тип данных у вас имеет поле `price`?

[Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61ec6/2) со строковой сортировкой и числовой.